# greatest common divisor of a cyclic group generator

Tags: group-theory

[image]

I have been struggling with this for a very long time-in fact for a few days and it's preventing me from progressing-a severe hurdle.

Mainly,

1) what is $$\left \langle a^{k} \right \rangle$$? Is it read as the cyclic group generated by some element a to the power of k?

2) Can I have a **step-by-step** explanation as to how $$\left \langle a^{k} \right \rangle  \sqsubseteq  \left \langle a^{d} \right \rangle$$?
To be specific, I cannot make the connection involved in **'and so'**

I spent a couple of hours a day looking at this but it's not helping.

Edit: The link provided to the duplicate was not at all clear.

Topic in the other post clearly did not addressed the poster's question. It has also not answered my question on the implicit assumption made.

Comment: @fkraiem does this requires knowledge of subgroup of a cyclic group?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: @fkraiem
Show explicitly that 
$$ \left \langle a^{k} \right \rangle  \sqsubseteq  \left \langle a^{d} \right \rangle$$

Is this clear enough?

Comment: You forgot the magic word. Also, I have done so in my answer to the linked question. If you don't understand something, ask a more precise (and polite) question.

Comment: @fkraiem 
I do not understand what is it about my question you are showing a lack of understanding of and considered that possibility that English might not be your first language so being explicit in my statement would be more efficient.
I read the question in the link and you mentioned:
$$\left(a^d\right)^e = a^{de} = a^k$ so $a^k \in \langle a^d\rangle$.$$
There is an implicit assumption you assumed the read to be aware of in the word "so". What is that implicit assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) $\left \langle a^{k} \right \rangle$ is the subgroup of whatever group $a$ comes from that is made of all powers of $a$. I.e. it is the subgroup

$$e, a, a^2, a^3, a^4, \ldots, a^{n-1}$$

Your quote says that $a$ is of order $n$, which means that $a^n=e$ (where $e$ is the identity), so this list includes all powers of $a$.

2) We have $d=\gcd(n,k),\ k=dr,\ a^k=(a^d)^r$. Therefore we also have $(a^k)^s=(a^d)^{rs}$. That shows that any power of $a^k$ is a power of $a^d$, so any power of $a^k$ is a member of the powers of $a^{\gcd(n,k)}$, so the set of powers of $a^k$ is a subset of the set of the powers of $a^{\gcd(n,k)}$, so

$$\left \langle a^{k} \right \rangle  \subseteq  \left \langle a^{d} \right \rangle$$

Is that clear?

Comment: While still fuzzy, it has helped and I should understand it after some refining.
I would have to trouble you, though, to explain a little more about on $$\left \langle a^{k} \right \rangle$$; 
is $$\left \langle a^{k} \right \rangle$$ the definition of a subgroup of a cyclic group?

Comment: @Mathematicing: No, it is the definition of the subgroup *of any kind of group* made of all the powers of $a$. It is easy to prove that this subset is also a subgroup. This subgroup is cyclic, but the main group need not be. This subgroup may be finite or infinite: in your particular problem you are told that it is finite. In the infinite case we need to include negative powers such as $a^{-2}$.

Comment: Very helpful. I see what contributed to my lack of understanding then.

Comment: Just want to say I got it! The everything become clear when I recalled gcd of 2 non-zero integers as a linear combination.